# I don't get the "package context" pop up when I using Intents for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-intent

[This is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HW0KK.png)

[This is screenshot from a video of what's supposed to should be on my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp2lS.png)

I just cant seem to get this package context message in the second last row of code

I have no idea why this is happening

Here is the video I got the screenshot from
https://youtu.be/lDq1iO1osRU?t=207

Update

I changed (MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class) to (v.getContext(), MainActivity.class)

[Im now getting this error message, is this because I'm using bluestacks as a virtual device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lejys.png)

Comment: Could you please share snippets of the code that might be relevant?

Comment: Well im trying to make a button that goes to another activity page and have a button on that page that comes back to the main page

Answer (score 0):

in Android Studio try to File -> Invalidate caches / Restart. this `packageContext` is just an information how this variable is named inside method you are calling, have nothing to do with actual code runtime, this isn't any bug (at least not in your code, maybe in Android Studio)

Comment: Nope, i just get this message when I hover over "Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymous android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class<com.example.onclick6.SecondActivity>)'"